# mongodb vs CRUD operation using spring boot

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, crud

## **Below is pom.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>DemoMongoDBProduc</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>DemoMongoDBProduc</name>
    <description>Say Hello To Boot Using Mongo</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>

// **Below is my main method**

    package com.mono.mongo.crud;

   import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
   import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoMongoDbProducApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoMongoDbProducApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

// **Below is my Controller class**

```
    package com.mono.mongo.crud.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.mono.mongo.crud.model.Person;
import com.mono.mongo.crud.service.PersonService;

@RestController 
public class PersonController {

    @Autowired
    private PersonService personService;
    
    @RequestMapping("/create")
    public String create(@RequestParam String firstName, @RequestParam String lastName, @RequestParam int age) {
        Person p = personService.create(firstName, lastName, age);
        return p.toString();
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/get")
    public Person getPerson(@RequestParam String firstName) {
        return personService.getByFirstName(firstName);
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/getAll")
    public List<Person> getAll(){
        return personService.getAll();
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/update")
    public String update(@RequestParam String firstName, @RequestParam String lastName, @RequestParam int age) {
        Person p = personService.update(firstName, lastName, age);
        return p.toString();
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/delete")
    public String delete(@RequestParam String firstName) {
        personService.delete(firstName);
        return "Deleted : "+firstName;
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/delete")
    public String deleteAll() {
        personService.deleteAll();
        return "Deleted all records";
    }
}
```

// **Below is my Service class**

```
   package com.mono.mongo.crud.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.mono.mongo.crud.model.Person;
import com.mono.mongo.crud.repository.PersonRepository;

@Service
public class PersonService {
    
    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;
    
    //  Create operation
    public Person create(String firstName, String lastName, int age)
    {
        return personRepository.save(new Person(firstName, lastName, age));
    }
    
    //  Retrieve operation
    public List<Person> getAll()
    {
        return personRepository.findAll();
    }
    public Person getByFirstName(String firstName)
    {
        return personRepository.findByFirstName(firstName);
    }
    
    //  Update Operation
    public Person update(String firstName, String lastName, int age)
    {
        Person p = personRepository.findByFirstName(firstName);
        p.setLastName(lastName);
        p.setAge(age);
        return personRepository.save(p);
    }
    
    //  Delete Operation
    public void deleteAll() {
        personRepository.deleteAll();
    }
    public void delete(String firstName) {
        Person p = personRepository.findByFirstName(firstName);
        personRepository.delete(p);
    }
}
```

// **Below is my PersonRepository class**

```
package com.mono.mongo.crud.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.mono.mongo.crud.model.Person;

@Repository

public interface PersonRepository extends MongoRepository<Person, String> {
    public Person findByFirstName(String firstName);
    public List<Person> findbyAge(int age);
//  public Person findByFirstName(String firstName);
//  public List<Person> findByAge(int age);
}
```

// **Below is my Service class**

```
    package com.mono.mongo.crud.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.mono.mongo.crud.model.Person;
import com.mono.mongo.crud.repository.PersonRepository;

@Service
public class PersonService {
    
    @Autowired
    private PersonRepository personRepository;
    
    //  Create operation
    public Person create(String firstName, String lastName, int age)
    {
        return personRepository.save(new Person(firstName, lastName, age));
    }
    
    //  Retrieve operation
    public List<Person> getAll()
    {
        return personRepository.findAll();
    }
    public Person getByFirstName(String firstName)
    {
        return personRepository.findByFirstName(firstName);
    }
    
    //  Update Operation
    public Person update(String firstName, String lastName, int age)
    {
        Person p = personRepository.findByFirstName(firstName);
        p.setLastName(lastName);
        p.setAge(age);
        return personRepository.save(p);
    }
    
    //  Delete Operation
    public void deleteAll() {
        personRepository.deleteAll();
    }
    public void delete(String firstName) {
        Person p = personRepository.findByFirstName(firstName);
        personRepository.delete(p);
    }
}
```

// **Below is my POJO class**

```
    package com.mono.mongo.crud.model;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document
public class Person {

    @Id
    String id;
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    int age;
    
    public Person(String firstName, String lastName, int age)
    {
        this.firstName=firstName;
        this.lastName=lastName;
        this.age=age;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }
    
    public String toString() {
        return "Person FirstName: "+firstName+" LastName: "+lastName+" age: "+age;
    }
}
```

I am using spring tool suite as IDE, MongoDB, Maven 3.2. I am trying to learn CRUD operation using MongoDB. But when I am running this code as Spring Boot App I am getting

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'personController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'personService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'personService': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'personRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'personRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property findbyAge found for type Person!

Can some one tell me where and what mistake I am doing

Here is the screenshot of the error I am getting:
[image: Error]

Comment: It's probably more helpful to only post relevant parts of your code and not half of your project. Not many people have the time to first read into loads of code. By analyzing your problem on your own first you can figure out which parts are relevant.

Comment: @Capricorn Yes I will keep this in mind and since I am new here and this was my first question so thought of giving all the details. Can you help me now, please?

Answer (score 0):

In your Repository class.

Rename interface method from

```
findbyAge(int age);
```

to

```
findByAge(int age);
```

Comment: If this solved your problem then you can upvote it and mark it as correct. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue. It was quite simple and I was doing a silly mistake.
In the Controller class for delete() method and deleteAll() method the @RequestMapping was delete like @RequestMapping("/delete") only, instead I have changed it to @RequestMapping("/deleteAll") for complete deletion and @RequestMapping("/delete") for the deleteByFirstName. And it worked for me.